# ORA-00913: too many values in oracle subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have  requirement to capture all the job offers extended to a candidate and  which one the candidate was finally hired into. I created two separate queries, one that captures all the offers and a subquery that captures only the jobs that each candidate was finally hired into. Problem when I combine the two queries I am getting the ORA-00913: too many values. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT DISTINCT h.pi_candidate_num,
                h.parent_pi_number,
                h.associate_name,
                j.job_family_name,
                j.organization_name,
                j.title,
                e.contest_number,
                e.pi_his_itm_app_trk_creation_dt offer_date
FROM   wc_hired_interns_fa h
INNER  JOIN wc_application_event_f e
ON     h.pi_candidate_num = e.pi_candidate_num
INNER  JOIN wc_job_information_d j
ON     e.job_info_row_wid = j.row_wid
WHERE  e.pi_his_itm_app_trk_creation_dt IN
       (SELECT DISTINCT e.pi_his_itm_app_trk_creation_dt
        FROM   wc_application_event_f e
        INNER  JOIN wc_hired_interns_fa h
        ON     h.pi_candidate_num = e.pi_candidate_num
        INNER  JOIN wc_job_information_d j
        ON     e.job_info_row_wid = j.row_wid
        WHERE  j.job_family_name IN ('MDP', 'ELP', 'Emerging Leader Program', 'Other')
        AND    e.pi_his_itm_app_trk_sts_name = 'Extended'
        AND    e.pi_his_itm_app_trk_step_name = 'Offer'
        AND    j.title NOT IN ('Student Ambassador Program for Eligible Summer Interns', 'Student Ambassador'))
AND    j.title IN (SELECT *
                   FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT j.title full_time_detail,
                                           rank() over(PARTITION BY e.pi_candidate_num ORDER BY e.pi_his_itm_app_trk_creation_dt DESC) AS rowrank
                           FROM   wc_hired_interns_fa h
                           INNER  JOIN wc_application_event_f e
                           ON     h.pi_candidate_num = e.pi_candidate_num
                           INNER  JOIN wc_job_information_d j
                           ON     e.job_info_row_wid = j.row_wid
                           AND    j.job_family_name IN ('MDP', 'ELP', 'Emerging Leader Program', 'Other')
                           AND    e.pi_his_itm_app_trk_sts_name = 'Hired - External'
                           AND    e.pi_his_itm_app_trk_step_name = 'Hire'
                           AND    j.title NOT IN ('Student Ambassador Program for Eligible Summer Interns', 'Student Ambassador'))
                   WHERE  rowrank = 1);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The immediate problem seems to be this part:

```
...
  AND J.TITLE IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT J.TITLE FULL_TIME_DETAIL,
        RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY E.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM ORDER BY E.PI_HIS_ITM_APP_TRK_CREATION_DT DESC) AS ROWRANK 
        FROM WC_HIRED_INTERNS_FA H
...
```

The `SELECT *` means that subquery is returning two column values, `FULL_TIME_DETAIL` and `ROWRANK`. You don't actually want `ROWRANK` there though, so change the `*` to the column you do want:

```
...
  AND J.TITLE IN (
    SELECT FULL_TIME_DETAIL FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT J.TITLE FULL_TIME_DETAIL,
        RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY E.PI_CANDIDATE_NUM ORDER BY E.PI_HIS_ITM_APP_TRK_CREATION_DT DESC) AS ROWRANK 
        FROM WC_HIRED_INTERNS_FA H
...
```

---

You are doing a lot of subqueries and repeating a lot of code, so this could probably be significantly simplified; maybe investigate analytic functions. That's rather outside the scope of this question and the specific error, though.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, however after making the changes you recommended even though the error cleared, I  not getting the results I expected, that is the job title that someone was hired for.

Comment: Like I said, that's outside the scope of this question. And as I think I commented on a previous question, you really need to provide [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain exactly what you want to see, and why your current code isn't doing what you want. That would need to be another new question though. I will hint, though, that your subqueries probably need to be joins (or eliminated) and you can use case expressions and maybe analytic functions to get closer to what i think you're aiming for; so you should probably explore that path and then ask a new question if stuck.